# How do I get `tightvnc` to report the version number on Ubuntu?

Tags: tightvnc

How do I get `tightvnc` to report the version number on Ubuntu?  The website [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/) does not offer any linux documentation; only Windows.

I am using the version installed by `apt-get install tightvncserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tightvncserver -help` will list the version number.

For documentation, you can always read the man page: `man tightvncserver` should tell you how to use all the basic options.

The output on my machine:

```
$ tightvncserver -help
TightVNC Server version 1.3.9

Usage: tightvncserver [<OPTIONS>] [:<DISPLAY#>]
       tightvncserver -kill :<DISPLAY#>

<OPTIONS> are Xtightvnc options, or:

        -name <DESKTOP-NAME>
        -depth <DEPTH>
        -geometry <WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>
        -httpport number
        -basehttpport number
        -alwaysshared
        -nevershared
        -pixelformat rgb<NNN>
        -pixelformat bgr<NNN>

See vncserver and Xtightvnc manual pages for more information.
```